# Problems rendering the api data on the screen to the user

Tags: javascript, react-native

[image: My return api is this]

how do I map these items in the component to render on the screen, I'm not sure because it's an array of objects and it contains "pacotes" which is also an array of objects, I made a filter to render only "pacotes"

```
useEffect(() => {
        const filtrando = teste.filter((item) => (item.pacotes))
        console.log(filtrando)
    }, [])
```

Comment: What component do you want to render? It is mainly an array. You can always to {filtrando.map((item, idx) => {<>/* your code */</>})}

Answer (score 0):

`filter` takes a callback that outputs a truthy or falsy value. It's used to remove elements from an array that don't match. An array is truthy, so your filter won't do anything, unless one of your items doesn't have a `pacotes` key.

You are probably looking for `.map`. `const filtrando = teste.map((item) => (item.pacotes))` will output an array that is only the `pacotes` array from the original items.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter